# Upload Data from Local System Ms Access to Web Sql Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, winforms

I have a windows forms application which maintains the billing details of a company's employees. The application stores and manipulates data in an MS Access database. 
I have to send the data every to the SQL Server Web database so that employees can see their monthly reports on the website.
My Code is :

```
Private Sub UploadData()
   Dim conn as New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Connection String Ms Access DB")
   Dim SCON = New SqlConnection(" Web SQL Sever Connection")
        Try
            SCON.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Exit Sub
        End Try
   Dim Qcmd As New SqlCommand("select query", SCON)
   Dim Cmd As New OleDbCommand("select id,acc,newacc,city,name,billduedateamt,oldbalance from Records where city = 'Delhi'", conn)
   Dim Mrdr As OleDbDataReader = Cmd.ExecuteReader
        Try
            While Mrdr.Read
                Qcmd.CommandText = "Insert into billing (acc,newacc,city,name,billduedateamt,oldbalance) Values (" + _
                        Mrdr.Item(0) + "," + Mrdr.Item(1) + ... Up to So On ")"
                Qcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End While
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            If SCON.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then
                SCON.Close()
            End If
            conn.Close()
        End Try

End Sub
```

It's too slow, is there any better code to do so?

Comment: Yes, there is. Sadly acthicetural advice is a little more complex than "fix my code for me, I have no clue what I can do". Let me jus tsay tha alternative solutions would not involve SQL but using a server on the central site likely with a web service or another way to accept a compressed data feed. Your core problem is "one insert after the next" over a high latency connection.

Comment: Can i sent or update the dataset to the Web Sql Server?

Comment: try to create one sql insert query in while and on finish to run this query... insert like this: 
 
INSERT INTO MyTable (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Bob'), (2, 'Peter'), (3, 'Joe');

Comment: @TotPeRo , Could you please answer me the code ?

Comment: Yeah. Multi row per insert would already work. This is basic SQL - read the documentation. YOu can insert multiple rows with one INSERT statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is Some short of code showing bulkcopy.

```
private static void PerformBulkCopyDifferentSchema()
{
    string connectionString = @"Server=
        localhost;Database=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=true";
    DataTable sourceData = new DataTable();
    // get the source data
    using (SqlConnection sourceConnection =
                    new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand myCommand =
            new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 5 * 
            FROM Products_Archive", sourceConnection);
        sourceConnection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
        // open the destination data
        using (SqlConnection destinationConnection =
                    new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            // open the connection
            destinationConnection.Open();
            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy =
                new SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection.ConnectionString))
            {
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("ProductID", "ProductID");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("ProductName", "Name");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("QuantityPerUnit", "Quantity");
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "Products_TopSelling";
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're only inserting data, use the Bulk Copy feature of SQL Server, which is surfaced via the `SqlBulkCopy` class in .NET.  Use a data adapter to populate a `DataTable` with data from Access and then use `SqlBulkCopy` to insert the lot into SQL Server as quickly as possible.

Comment: Could you please give me an example or link of a code to use SqlBulkCopy?

Comment: No. I'm not here to write your code for you so that you don't have to bother. Do some research and learn something about it, then make an effort on your own behalf. If you have an issue, post a new question on that specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Private Sub UploadData()
Dim conn as New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Connection String Ms Access DB")
Dim SCON = New SqlConnection(" Web SQL Sever Connection")
    Try
        SCON.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try
Dim Qcmd As New SqlCommand("select query", SCON)
Dim Cmd As New OleDbCommand("select id,acc,newacc,city,name,billduedateamt,oldbalance from Records where city = 'Delhi'", conn)

Dim Mrdr As OleDbDataReader = Cmd.ExecuteReader
    Try
       Dim sqlInsert as String="Insert into billing (acc,newacc,city,name,billduedateamt,oldbalance) "
        While Mrdr.Read
            sqlInsert = sqlInsert +  " Values (" + _
                    Mrdr.Item(0) + "," + Mrdr.Item(1) + ... Up to So On ")"

        End While
         Qcmd.CommandText = sqlInsert
            Qcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        If SCON.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then
            SCON.Close()
        End If
        conn.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Do **NOT** string together your SQL statements! This is madness - it opens the doors for **SQL injection** attacks, it's messy, it's error-prone - **don't do it!**. Instead: use **parametrized queries - ALWAYS, no exceptions!**

Comment: @marc_s : you have right but this is not Web application to do SQL injection and if the application is used by trusted users not on the web or from unknown users is not necessarily to parametrize.

Comment: ***ALWAYS*** use parametrized queries - ***NO*** exceptions, no scenario where it's not necessary - just don't even think about doing it with string concetenation! Seriously. ***NEVER*** use string concatenation to build your SQL statements.